# Converting a Knockoutjs HTML line to Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, knockout.js

I have that line :

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Price" id="Price" class="form title radius width-7"/>
```

How can I convert that using @Html.EditorFor (Razor) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the appropriate validation attributes to your model property, then write

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.price, new { @class = form title radius width-7" })
```

Comment: You are right about validation attributes, but I need add that also : data-bind="value: Price"... Knockoutjs !

Comment: Then add `, data_bind = "..."` to the second parameter.  The `_` will be converted to a `-`.